# Is there a way to make only two items be on an embed inline? (Discord.js)

Tags: discord.js, formatting, inline

as the title suggests, I am wondering if there is any way I could make it so there are only 2 items per line for a discord embed instead of 3. The goal would be something like this -

```
Item 1 -        Item 2 -
(Description)   (Description)

Item 3 -        Item 4 -
(Description)   (Description)

Item 5 -        Item 6 -
(Description)   (Description)
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.addField('\u200b', '\u200b')` to create an empty field

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('RANDOM')
  .addField('Item 1 -', '(Description)', true)
  .addField('Item 2 -', '(Description)', true)
  .addField('\u200b', '\u200b')
  .addField('Item 3 -', '(Description)', true)
  .addField('Item 4 -', '(Description)', true)
  .addField('\u200b', '\u200b')
  .addField('Item 5 -', '(Description)', true)
  .addField('Item 6 -', '(Description)', true)

message.channel.send({
  embeds: [embed]
})
```

[image: Something like this]

EDIT:

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('RANDOM')
  .addField('Item 1 -', '(Description)', true)
  .addField('Item 2 -', '(Description)', true)
  .addField('** **', '** **')
  .addField('Item 3 -', '(Description)', true)
  .addField('Item 4 -', '(Description)', true)
  .addField('** **', '** **')
  .addField('Item 5 -', '(Description)', true)
  .addField('Item 6 -', '(Description)', true)

message.channel.send({
  embeds: [embed]
})
```

Comment: Thank you, that works, but is there any way I could make it so there isn't a huge gap in between rows?

Comment: So far I don't have any other way to minimize the gap for it sorry.

Comment: I've figured it out about putting a small blank space every fields. I hope you see this, check my edited answer.